# How can I drop elements in certain positions from a list using Drop?

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix

```
a = Table[i, {i, 1, 10}]
Drop[a, {5, 8}]
```

If go with the above procedure, it will delete all the elements from between position 5 to 8. How can I drop elements which are at position 5 and position 8 using `Drop`?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use instead `Delete`, in this way:

```
a = Table[i, {i, 1, 10}];
Delete[a, {{5}, {8}}]
```

(*

{1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 9, 10}

*)

By the way, you can be far more efficient:

```
a = Range[10]
```

Comment: can we give the list of position  which I wanted to drop like {3,5,8,9}

Comment: `Delete[a,{{3},{5},{8},{9}}]`

Comment: Also `Delete[a, Partition[{3, 5, 8, 9}, 1]]` comes to mind... if the list of positions gets longer.

Comment: In general, you can use `Delete[a, List/@{3, 5, 8, 9}]`.

Answer (score 6):

```
Drop[a, {5, 8, 3}]
```

> {1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 9, 10}

```
Fold[Drop[#, {#2}] &, a, Reverse[{5, 8}]]
```

> {1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 9, 10}

Answer (score 1):

```
list = Range[10];

p = {5, 8};
```

Using `SubsetReplace` (new in 12.1)

```
SubsetReplace[list, p :> Nothing]
```

{1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 9, 10}

Answer (score 1):

```
list = Range[10];
```

Using `SequenceCases`:

```
p = {5, 8};

SequenceCases[list, s : {Except[Alternatives @@ p]} :> Splice@s]

(*{1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 9, 10}*)
```